# vkCreateInstance() taking an unreasonable amount of time with validation layers and VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vulkan

I noticed my Vulkan program takes almost 10 seconds before actually responding after window creation; after some testing, I got the cause down to `vkCreateInstance()`.

Here's the interesting part: this issue **only occurs when running through VSCode** - debugging or no debugging - **and** if the program is making use of **validation layers** (`VK_EXT_debug_utils`). That is to say the following:

The program **works** under the following conditions:

- It is being run stand-alone (no VSCode) *with* debug utils
- It is being run stand-alone (no VSCode) *without* debug utils
- It is being run in VSCode, *without* debug utils

But the program **does not work** when:

- It is being run in VSCode *with* debug utils.

*(By 'work' I mean run without any significant delays)*

I am on **Linux** with a **Radeon RX 480**, using **RADV** (Mesa) drivers.

## Update 1

Looks like I wasn't using a validation layer when creating the instance - now I have done that, and the following output is returned during `vkCreateInstance()` *when launching via VSCode*:

```
[vlk] Searching for layer manifest files
[vlk]    In following folders:
[vlk]       /home/jack/.config/vulkan/implicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /etc/xdg/vulkan/implicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /etc/vulkan/implicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /usr/local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d
[vlk]    Found the following files:
[vlk]       /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamfossilize_i386.json
[vlk]       /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json
[vlk]       /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json
[vlk]       /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamfossilize_x86_64.json
[vlk]       /usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/amd_icd64.json
[vlk]       /usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/amd_icd32.json
[vlk] Found manifest file /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamfossilize_i386.json (file version "1.0.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json (file version "1.0.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json (file version "1.0.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamfossilize_x86_64.json (file version "1.0.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/amd_icd64.json (file version "1.0.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/amd_icd32.json (file version "1.0.0")
[vlk] Searching for layer manifest files
[vlk]    In following folders:
[vlk]       /home/jack/.config/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /etc/xdg/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /home/jack/.local/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /usr/local/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
[vlk]       /usr/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
[vlk]    Found the following files:
[vlk]       /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_screenshot.json
[vlk]       /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_monitor.json
[vlk]       /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_api_dump.json
[vlk]       /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_device_simulation.json
[vlk]       /usr/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_khronos_validation.json
[vlk] Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_screenshot.json (file version "1.2.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_monitor.json (file version "1.0.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_api_dump.json (file version "1.2.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_device_simulation.json (file version "1.2.0")
[vlk] Found manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_khronos_validation.json (file version "1.2.0")
[vlk] Searching for driver manifest files
[vlk]    In following folders:
[vlk]       /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json
[vlk]    Found the following files:
[vlk]       /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json
[vlk] Found ICD manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
[vlk] Searching for ICD drivers named /usr/lib/libvulkan_radeon.so
[vlk] Build ICD instance extension list
[vlk] Loading layer library libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so
[vlk] Insert instance layer VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation (libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so)
[vlk] /usr/lib32/amdvlk32.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
[vlk] Loading layer library /usr/lib/amdvlk64.so
[vlk] Insert instance layer VK_LAYER_AMD_switchable_graphics_64 (/usr/lib/amdvlk64.so)
[vlk] Requested layer VK_LAYER_AMD_switchable_graphics_32 was wrong bit-type.
[vlk] Build ICD instance extension list
```

The output log is the same outside of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Are there any log messages being emitted from `vkCreateInstance`?

Comment: @vandench - I've fixed the program so as to print log messages during `vkCreateInstance`. Since the resulting log was quite long, I've added it to the question as an update. There seems to be some concerning output near the bottom; could this indicate the problem?

Comment: Assuming those logs are generated by calling `vkCreateInstance` when the validation layer is enabled then this may have to do with VS Code redirecting `stdout` in an odd way.

Comment: @vandench - I have added yet another update with new information regarding the output when calling `vkCreateInstance`. Turns out, running the program outside of VS Code - even when the environment is exactly identical otherwise - leads to very different logs, which suggest very different behaviour on Vulkan's part. So I don't *think* it's just `stdout` being redirected.

Comment: `VK_ICD_FILENAMES` doesn't appear to be set outside of VS code and thus it is searching through all drivers. The line about the 32 bit version of the RADV driver can be ignored, a couple of lines down it recognizes the 64 bit version of the RADV driver as valid. It's thus likely that VS code is slow because the RADV driver is slow, and outside VS code is fast because it's trying to use the AMD driver.

Comment: @vandench - Admittedly, I thought I was setting `VK_ICD_FILENAMES` outside of VS Code but I wasn't -_-. However, I am now definitely setting it, the logs seem to be much more similar to those printed from in VS Code, and yet it is still instant outside of VS Code. So yes, I was definitely doing things wrong before - but now that they're fixed, the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking more into the issue, I have found a workaround that, whilst it doesn't completely eliminate the delay, minimises it to *almost* instant. About ~8-9 seconds down to an average of about ~2-3. Not perfect, but leagues ahead of the previous time.

It turns out it was **GDB** that, for whatever reason, caused this delay. Maybe something that someone on either the GDB or Vulkan team should look into? I don't know. In any case, VSCode was using GDB to debug the program.

So to fix the problem: **use LLDB instead.** Luckily I'm not limited to using GDB for any reason and LLDB seems to be a perfectly good debugger as well. There might be others I don't know about that work even better... I'll look further into it at some point in the future.

In my case, since I use VSCode, [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) was useful for integrating LLDB into the launch.json system that Code has.